# Getting DNN Site To Run Locally

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke

I am trying to get a DotNetNuke site running locally.

At the moment the site is hosted on a server and is functional.

I downloaded the website to my local computer and tried to compile it in Visual Studio.

I am getting all sorts of build errors and I am having alot of trouble getting it to run.

The version of DotNetNuke is very old. i believe it is version 05.06.02.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can access some of the DNN code via Visual Studio, first you need to get the site running without Visual Studio.

Here is a good set of instructions on copying and running a site on another computer.

http://www.ifinity.com.au/2012/09/05/Creating_a_test_copy_of_your_DotNetNuke_website

The main things to pay attention too are getting a connection to your database, and making the  IIS site accessible locally.

Comment: Thanks, this was good advice. I managed to get the site to run locally, and I figured this old version of DotNetNuke is not able to compile in Visual Studio as it comiles at run time, or at least this is what I am lead to believe.

Comment: @TrentStewart A normal DNN site install only includes source for they dynamically compiled portions of the site, which is a relatively small portion of the total code.  There are complete source packages available, but you only need them if you are changing the DNN platform itself, not for building/maintaining a site.